# IN ANY DETAIL or IN EVERY DETAIL?

Tags: grammar, difference

I have an excercise took me so much time but i can’t still understand the different.

“The staff of the document storage facility followed the auditor’s suggestions for corrective action in **Any**/**Every** detail.” The correct choice is **Every**.

But from what i know, if i say “ this excercise is very easy, any student could solve it well”, it means that you choose randomly a studen, no matter how many times you select student, the first one will do it well, either is the second one, the third is same as well, etc. Till the end of student group. So, the sentence is referring to All member of group.This is a case I think that there is no difference between Any and Every, though there are many other case that ANY is difference clearly from EVERY that I understand.

If i’m not wrong at my sentence, why can’t I apply it’s case to my question to have ANY to be correct choice ?. I hope you guys could help me understand it clearly. THANK YOU!

Comment: Please do not use all caps. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

"He followed the auditor's suggestion in ***every*** detail". It would not make sense to use ***any*** in this instance - because he followed ***every one*** of the details.

"***Any*** student could have done it" is different. But it means almost exactly the same thing as "***Every*** student could have done it". These two sentences are to all intents synonymous.